# Using elements of numpy array as index of another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an unknown 2D numpy array like the following:

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [0, 2],
])
```

I want to use the elements of the array as an index to another array b to produce the following effect:

```
b = np.random.randn(5, 5)
c = b[[1, 2], [0, 2]]
```

How can I use the variable a to replace the hardcoded values in the index?

Using the following code did not work:

```
b = np.random.randn(5, 5)
c = [*a]
```

As the * expression is used in an index.

Comment: Is the number of rows on `a` always equal to `2`?

Comment: no it is a 2D array where the size is not known when writing the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the outer layer of `a` to a tuple to trigger advanced indexing: `b[tuple(a)]`.

This is pretty much how the index syntax of `b[[1, 2], [0, 2]]` is interpreted; the elements are changed to NumPy arrays and are put into a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got it but, try using a list for the index instead of an np array:

```
import numpy as np

a = [
    [1, 2],
    [0, 2]
    ]

b = np.random.randn(5, 5)
c = b[a]
```

Comment: This will work for now, but NumPy is planning to change the default treatment of non-tuples `arr[tuple(not_a_tuple)]` to `arr[np.array(not_a_tuple)]`, which does something different. This code currently prints a `FutureWarning` that suggests you write `arr[tuple(not_a_tuple)]` for future versions.